# MegaRaid and power failures

Tags: electrical-power, megaraid

I have a server that is currently working on migrating a RAID setup. There are 36 drives connected to an AVAGO 3108 MegaRAID, and as of this moment, the estimated time remaining is ~13 days. It's been running for a while, and the estimate has decreased in accordance with time passed, indicating that it is most likely somewhat correct.

However, I have reasons to believe that I will most likely lose power in the weekends, as it is temporarily on an unstable power supply. This means that there will most likely be two power outages before it finishes. While I've rebooted the server a few times during the rebuild (and at one point having it all the way off before turning on again), I was wondering, how well (if at all) do RAID controllers generally handle power failure during RAID migration? I am currently leaning towards erring on the safe side, by shutting everything off on friday, and resume on monday, but that would lose me a few days that I would prefer not to lose.

It is worth noting that the system is running on an UPS, so the issue with the supply will not cause power surges or flickering.

Comment: Is the RAID currently under rebuild or only migration ?

Comment: @Overmind migration. I added another disk to a RAID5 the other day.

Comment: So practically your RAID is migrating in order to add that extra disk. In such a case, in a power-failure situation, it should continue where it left off, but in case a disk fails during that it may become degraded.